# implement the assign operator overload in a hashmap

Tags: c++

I'm working on the implementation of a hashmap in c++, however, there is an operation I want to do

```
myMap["key"] = value;
```

How can I implement this?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want this to work like the standard library `map` where if no entry exists with that key, an object is default initialized?

Comment: Do you mean to overload `operator[]`?

Comment: Yes, I have already implemented an insert method that takes that into account but I don't know if it's better to add a conditional here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to implement the map's index access `operator []`, which should return a reference to the corresponding value.

Then using that reference you can directly update the value.

Note: normally in C++ the map's `operator []` automatically creates an entry when one does not exist.

It's good to first create helper methods `find()`, which should return a (potentially empty) iterator, and `insert()` to create a new entry. Then `operator []` can be implemented simply as:

```
T& Map<T>::operator[] (Key const& key) {
    auto it = find(key);
    if it == end() {
        it = insert(std::make_pair(key, T::value_type()));
    }
    return it->second;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `find`, you want `lower_bound`, then you have an iterator pointing to where it should go as a hint to `insert`

Comment: @Caleth well yes some optimization is possible, except in case of a hash map it's not lower_bound but a hash + bucket.